# I want to rotate and delete the 3d model in android using sceneform sdk through buttons instead of gestures

Tags: arcore, sceneform

AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(fragment.getTransformationSystem());
        node.setRenderable(renderable);
        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
        node.select();

Answer (score 2):

Create or use an `anchorNode` from the anchor.

```
val anchor = arFragment.arSceneView.session.createAnchor(it)
val anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.arSceneView.scene)
```

Use `anchorNode.localPosition` & `anchorNode.localRotation` methods to rotate/change position.

```
anchorNode.localPosition = Vector3(tx(), ty(), tz())
anchorNode.localRotation = Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3(qx(), qy(), qz()), qw())
```

`anchor.detach()` removes the anchor from the scene.